# Android Studio : Config and system paths seem to be equal

Tags: android, android-studio

When I install Android studio, it launches with this message and exits giving this message:

```
Config and system paths seem to be equal.

If you have modified 'idea.config.path' or 'idea.system.path' properties,
please make sure they point to different directories, otherwise please re-install the IDE.
```

I tried re-installing it and uncommenting the path in `.idea` files from `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin` this file, Then it works but gives some other error saying :

`It seems you're using 'idea.system.path' property to specify the location of the caches directory. In 2020.1, default locations of application directories were changed. For compatibility, the IDE picked the old location of logs, but to avoid any ambiguity in the future (and to get rid of this warning) please set 'idea.log.path' property, too.`.

Any idea on what is wrong with me?

Answer (score 2):

You can configure `idea.system.path` and `idea.log.path` in `idea.properties` file.

To configure

1. Press Shift-Key twice to open Search Everywhere Dialog.
2. Type "Edit Custom Properties" in the search box
3. Click on the first option to open `idea.properties` in the editor window.

[image: Edit Custom Properties]

In the editor window, type in the properties with appropriate path.
Do ensure the directories exist.

`idea.system.path=e:/android/studio/caches`

`idea.log.path=e:/android/studio/log`

Save and close the file. Restart Android Studio for the changes to get effected.

Defining `idea.system.path` is one of  recommendation by **Android Studio** to move set of directories outside %USERPROFILE% for optimizing build performance.

Please refer to https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config?utm_source=android-studio#antivirus-impact

Comment: I dont even remember which project showed this error, the problem was long back. Anyway thankyou for your answer, it may help others